# How can I run external commands of Windows Cmd on Windows Bash Shell?

Tags: linux, windows, cmd

I had recently turned on the Windows 10 bash shell. I can run all the linux commands. But how can i run the npm commands that I use to run on cmd? I have npm already installed but the commands i want to run does not work on bash.